# WebDriver.IO configuration not loading any Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cucumber, webdriver-io, wdio

I have a suite of UI tests built on WebDriver.IO and Cucumber JS, where I am attempting to load a Chrome extension before starting the test steps. I have tried both ways of loading an extension outlined in the [Web Extension Testing docs provided by WDIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/extension-testing/web-extensions/), but neither one has been successful so far.

Adding the `load-extension` argument to the list of args in `goog:chromeOptions` has not worked when passing in the folder containing the unpacked extension files like so:

```
const extensionPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test');
// This resolves to /Users/<username>/<app>/test, which contains a .js file and manifest.json
...

capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome'
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: [`load-extension=${extensionPath}`]
      // I've tried this arg with and without adding -- as a prefix
    }
  }],
```

I have also tried injecting a bundled .crx file in the `extensions` array like below, which is also not working:

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome'
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: [],
      extensions = [(await fs.readFile(`${extensionPath}.crx`)).toString('base64')];
    }
  }],
```

I'm curious if anyone has any tips or knows of other configuration settings that might affect this. I've tried modifying or disabling our other config settings to no success. The extension loads correctly when I manually install it in the browser, but when running through WDIO I get no feedback or error messages.

Thanks!

Edit: Checked logs on Haxor's recommendation below, I think they may show what the problem is. During the browser's initialization the logs show all the enabled flags like so:

```
2023-09-27T15:34:41.648Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome (undefined) with flags: --enable-automation -—disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling —-disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows -—disable-sync —-metrics-recording-only -—disable-default-apps —-mute-audio —-no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost -—disable-client-side-phishing-detection —-password-store=basic -—use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages -—disable-breakpad -—disable-dev-shm-usage —-disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess —-disable-features=site-per-process, TranslateUI, BlinkGenPropertyTrees
--window-position=0,0 —-window-size=1200,900 —-window-size=1600,1200 --load-extension=/Users/<username>/<app>/test
```

Specifically it looks like `--disable-extensions` is being added somewhere in the process, even though I'm not manually setting it anywhere in my code.

Comment: 1. Can you give the complete logs for the execution with the `--logLevel trace` enabled?


2. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Thank you, logs showed something that could be useful (edited question above). Looks like `--disable-extensions` flag is being added to the browser at some point in the setup process, even though I am not manually defining it. Currently digging through devtools & other libraries to see if any part of the stack defaults to not allow extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The devtools service was using Puppeteer, which sets `--disable-extensions` as one of its default flags. The solution was to add a new section to the capability:

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome'
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: [`load-extension=${extensionPath}`]
    }
    'wdio:devtoolsOptions': {
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']
    },
  }],
```

which filters that flag out, allowing the extension to load. Discovered the setting in [WDIO's config file documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile/)